# Android TextView Not Wraping up the text for hindi text

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-styles

Currently I faced a problem in an application when I was trying to display text on text view which is HINDI font text on a textView it does not wrap it. It look like 
[image]

My `TextView` code is

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Wrap the width instead fill Parent.

Comment: post your android (java class) code

Answer (score 0):

Try following properly for TextView

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:maxLines="100"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: @SumitPatel try to change width as  wrap_content `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: @SumitPatel It's working for me. Ok give width fixed value like 300dp

Answer (score 0):

Add this for your `TextView`:

```
android:ellipsize="none"
android:singleLine="false"
```